# Iterating and comparing big data set

Tags: java

Basically I receive a 2 big data lists from 2 different database, the list looks like this:

```
List 1:
=============
A000001
A000002
A000003
.
.
A999999

List 2:
=============
121111
000111
000003
000001
.
.
```

I need to compare two list and find out each data which is in `List 1` is available in `List 2` **(after appending some standard key to it)**, so that  and if it is available put it in 3rd list for further manipulation. As an example `A000001` is available in `List 1` as well as in `List 2` **(after appending some standard key to it)** so I need to put it in 3rd list.

Basically I have this code, it does like this for each row in `List 1`, I'm iterating through all data in `List 2` and doing comparison. (Both are array list)

```
List<String> list1 = //Data of list 1 from db
List<String> list2 = //Data of list 2 from db

for(String list1Item:list1) {
   for(String list2Item:list2) {
     String list2ItemAfterAppend = "A" + list2Item;
     if(list1Item.equalsIgnoreCase(list2ItemAfterAppend)) {
        //Add it to 3rd list
     }
   }
}
```

Yes, this logic works fine, but I feel this is not efficient way to iterate list. After putting timers, it's taking 13444 milliseconds on average for 2000x5000 list of data. My question is, is there any other logic you people can think of or suggest me to improve the performance of this code?

I hope I'm clear, if not please let me know if I can improve question.

Comment: Also, please let me know if it's off topic for this site here, I can happily migrate to other stackexchange site as required.

Comment: sort `list2` and then use a binary search to find your match.  (Read the `java.util.Arrays` API, both are in there)

Comment: do you have case sensitivity issue like list one can have AGJ and two can have agj

Comment: Can there be duplicates in either of the two lists?

Comment: @PavneetSingh no, there's no such thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes there can be.

Comment: Sort the list and then  searc for the first item of list1 in list2, using a binary search in list2. if it exists, you can ignore all the items of list2 upto that item, and move to the next item.

Comment: This is going to be some work to do in Java.  Are you sure you can't handle this in SQL, which is a much better tool for this job?

Comment: If some entry appears 3 times in list one, and 2 times in list two, then how many times should it appear in your final result?

Comment: then i recommend to simply use contains function instead of `equals` and eliminate creation of new string

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately no, as I don't have control on those services.

Comment: Ok, I will try your and binary search suggestion..

Comment: do you want to keep the duplicate values too in 3rd list

Comment: @PavneetSingh that's not a issue for me actually, I can convert arraylist to set.

Comment: It _is_ an issue for you, because a set will strip out all duplicates, possibly creating problems later on.

Comment: as i said use contains and use `break`  inside `if` after the first match , no need to go further

Answer (score 1):

You can order both list, then using only one loop iterate on both value, switching which index increments depending on which value is the biggest. Something like:

```
boolean isWorking = true;
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
int index1 = 0;
int index2 = 0;

while(isWorking){
    String val1 = list1.get(index1);
    String val2 = "A" + list2.get(index2);
    int compare = val1.compareTo(val2)

    if(compare == 0){
        list3.add(val1);
        index1++;
        index2++;
    }else if (compare > 0){
        val2++;
    }else{ // if(compare < 0)
        val1++;
    }

    isWorking = !(index1 == list1.size() || index2 == list2.size() );
}
```

Be carefull about what kind of List you're using. The `get(int i)` on `LinkedList` is expensive, whereas it is not on an `ArrayList`. Also, you might want to save `list1.size()` and `list2.size()`, I dont't think it calcluates it everytime, but chek it. I'm not sure if it's really usefull/efficient, but you can initialise list3 with the size of the smallest of both list (taking into acount the loadFactor, look up for it), so list3 doesnt have to resize everytime.

The code above is not tested (maybe switch `val1++` and `val2++`), but you get the idea. I believe it's faster than yours (because it's O(n+m) rather than O(n*m) but I'll let you see (both `sort()` and `compareTo()` will add some time compared to your method, but normally it shouldn't be too much). If you can, use your RDBMS to sort both list when you get them (so you don't have to do it in the Java code)

Answer (score 0):

---

I think the problem is how big the list is and how much memory you have.
For me for under 1 million records, I will use a HashSet to make it faster.
Code may like:

```
Set<String> set1 = //Data of list 1 from db, when you get the data you make it a Set instead of a List. HashSet is enough for you to use.
List<String> list2 = //Data of list 2 from db
```

Then you just need to:

```
for(String list2Item:list2) {
    if(set1.contains("A" + list2Item) {
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi Daisy, if he wants to retain duplicates in the first list, then a set would not be suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection method from apache commons. Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A000001","A000002","A000003");
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("121111","000111","000001");
        List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.stream().forEach((s) -> {list3.add("A"+s);});
        Collection<String> common =  CollectionUtils.intersection(list1, list3);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `Stream` API for this, the code to create the new list with Streams is very concise and straightforward and probably very similar in performance:

```
    List<String> list3 = list2.stream()
                              .map(s->"A"+s)
                              .filter(list1::contains)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the list are big, you could try to process the list in parallel and use multiple threads to process the list. This **may or may not** improve the performance. Doing some measures its important to check if processing the list in parallel is actually improving the performance.

To process the stream in parallel, you only need to call the method `parallel` on the stream:

```
    List<String> list3 = list2.stream()
                              .parallel()
                              .map(s->"A"+s)
                              .filter(list1::contains)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing a lot of String manipulation, 'equalsIgnoreCase' convert the Characters to upper/lower case. This is being executed in your inner loop and the size of your list is 5000x2000, so the String manipulation is being done millions of times.

Ideally, get your Strings in either upper or lower case from the database and avoid the conversion inside the inner loop. If this is not possible, probably converting the case of the String at the beginning improves the performance.

Then, you could create a new list with the elements of one of the lists and keep all the elements present in the other list, the code with the uppercase conversion could be:

```
list1.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>(list2);
list3.replaceAll(s->"A"+s.toUpperCase());
list3.retainAll(list1);
```